# Write multiple streams to a single file without knowing the length of the streams?

Tags: file-io, compression, san

For performance of reading and writing a large dataset, we have multiple threads compressing and writing out separate files to a SAN.  I'm making a new file spec that will instead have all these files appended together into a single file. I will refer to each of these smaller blocks of a data as a subset.

Since each subset will be an unknown size after compression there is no way to know what byte offset to write to. Without compression each writer can write to a predictable address.

Is there a way to append files together on the file-system level without requiring a file copy?

I'll write an example here of how I would expect the result to be on disk. Although I'm not sure how helpful it is to write it this way.

```
single-dataset.raw
[header 512B][data1-45MB][data2-123MB][data3-4MB][data5-44MB]
```

I expect the SAN to be NTFS for now in case there are any special features of certain file-systems.

If I make the subsets small enough to fit into ram, I will know the size after compression, but keeping them smaller has other performance drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use sparse files.  Just position each subset at some offset "guaranteed" to be beyond the last subset.  Your header can then contain the offset of each subset and the filesystem handles the big "empty" chunks for you.

The cooler solution is to write out each subset as a separate file and then use low-level filesystem functions to join the files by chaining the first block of the next file to the last block of the previous file (along with deleting the directory entries for all but the first file).

Comment: If I use sparse files I would need someway of detecting if the filesystem can handle that.

Comment: I like the cooler solution. I wanted some actual pointers on how to do something like that.